# How much time can take a truncate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using the next statement to truncate a table in sql server DB: 
`truncate table aaa.table1`

The table data space is 230,133 MB in 400141 rows.

The statemen has run about 2:30 h and does not finish...

If I use `EXEC sp_rename` to rename table, and the create a table copying this, it takes too much time as do on the truncate operation.

Anyone know how to solve that or possible reasons?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably table is locked. Did you check for locks. For `400141` records `TRUNCATE` command will hardly take a second or two

Comment: To follow on for this, when you run the truncate you can use the command EXEC sp_who2. Look in the column Blk By to see if you have any blocking occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Prdp
I see Blk By 268, status suspended. What does it mean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RichBenner. I used DBCC Inputbuffer (268) and I know the event. Now I am trying to kill that...

Comment: @Maik it means that the user under SPID 268 is locking the table. You can run DBCC INPUTBUFFER (268) to see what query is running on that connection and decide what to do with it.

Comment: Check what is happening in `268` session. `aaa.table1` is used in that session. So the `TRUNCATE` command is waiting for the `268` session to release the `aaa.table1`

Comment: @RichBenner I find that, another process has blocked the table. I kill this and then run the truncate statement and all is ok. Thanks for your help!